# Navigation after form completion the react/redux way

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an action that I call to save a `Brand` that looks like this:

```
export function createBrand(props) {
  return function(dispatch) {
  postData('brands', props)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_BRAND_SUCCESS,
        payload: response
      });
      browserHistory.push("/brands/" + response.data.id);
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch({type: CREATE_BRAND_ERROR});
    });
  }
}
```

This is called from a component. My question is around the `browserHistory.push("/brands/" + response.data.id);` which takes the user to the edit page for the brand they just saved. Is this the appropriate way/place to do this? Should I be responding to the CREATE_BRAND_SUCCESS dispatch event in the component itself instead? If so, what would that look like?

Comment: This looks perfectly fine to me. I don't see any benefit to listen to CREATE_BRAND_SUCCESS instead. Does this approach give some limitation to you, or are you just ensuring you follow the best practices?

Comment: Just want to make sure I'm following best practices and getting the most bang for my buck feature wise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the approach you're taking. It looks like you're using redux-thunk. I don't think it's a best practice to respond to events in the component. The only ways to do that (that I can think of) would be to create some custom middleware for checking the action type, then calling a method on your component (please don't do this) or using your reducers to keep some state around in the component like `responsesFromApi: [response1, response2]`.

The approach I like most is to use tools that let me kick off [declarative effects](https://medium.com/@maxheiber/why-i-wrote-a-redux-async-outerware-277d450dba74#.wh0hkpuwy) in the reducer while keeping the reducer pure. [Redux Loop](https://github.com/redux-loop/redux-loop) and my own redux-funk enable this. I like this approach, because the answer to "what happens when this action is dispatched" can be found in one place (the reducers). And declarative effects are easier to test.

So the way you'd do this with [redux-funk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-funk) is:

```
// in component.js in mapDispatchToProps
dispatch({
    type: REQUEST_CREATE_BRAND, ...brandObject
});

// in reducer
const requestCreateBrand = brandName => postData('brands', brandName).catch(() => {type: CREATE_BRAND_FAILURE})

const navigateToBrand = id => browserHistory.push(`/brands/${id}`)

...

case REQUEST_CREATE_BRAND:
     call(action, [requestCreateBrand, [action.brandName]])
     return {...state, isRequesting: true}
case CREATE_BRAND_SUCCESS:
     call(action, [navigateToBrand, [id]])
     return {...state, isRequesting: false, brands: {...state.brands, [action.brandId]: action.brand}
```

...

You can also create declarative effects using the `call` function in [Redux Saga](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html)